# Как определить, является ли тип кастомным, или он является типом из FCL/BCL?

Tags: c#, .net

Привет всем!

Играюсь с рефлексией, пробегаясь по полям класса, как можно определить, тип этого поля является родным для `.net framework`, или он является кастомным (например, определенный в проекте класс типа `MyClass`)?

Comment: Может вас устроит список из CLS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть два варианта:

1. Можно прочитать свойство сборки `AssemblyCompany`, у большинства классов стандартной библиотеки это свойство имеет значение `"Microsoft"`.
2. Можно проверить `public key token` сборки, у сборок BCL он будет `b77a5c561934e089` или `b03f5f7f11d50a3a`, у сборок WPF - `31bf3856ad364e35`.

Стоит учесть, что ни один из этих методов (и даже их комбинация) не даст точного ответа на ваш вопрос. Например, не все сборки, входящие в поставку .NET являются стандартными, произведёнными Microsoft'ом. А сборки, входящие в Mono вообще не имеют к Microsoft'у никакого отношения.

Источник: [C# class type - How to determine whether it is a standard .net framework class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777920/c-sharp-class-type-how-to-determine-whether-it-is-a-standard-net-framework-cl)

Comment: Т.е., способа с получением массива стандартных классов не существует?) Ну, т.е., получили список стандартных классов .net, не нашли там свой класс - значит кастомный. Нашли - значит он не кастомный)

Comment: Насколько мне известно, такого способа не существует. Возможно, кто-то ещё сможет вам помочь, но я пас.

Comment: Судя по всему, списка не существует, и по очень простой причине: классов много, категорий много, и на всех пользователей списков не напасёшься. Вместо этого вы можете пройтись reflection'ом по Microsoft'овским сборкам и составить себе список во время выполнения. Какие именно сборки включать в список, вы знаете сами, т.к. сами же включали их в список зависимостей своего проекта, правильно?

Comment: Согласно [Википедии](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_Class_Library), к BCL относятся лишь отдельные пространства имён (namespace). Так что можно в принципе проверить, лежит ли тип в одном из этих пространств имён, и если да, кем подписана сборка.