# Сколько всего сейчас стандартных классов в C# .net?

Tags: c#, .net

Несколько версий назад было 40000, а сейчас как сосчитать?

Comment: что вы подразумеваете под стандартным?

Comment: для чего такое знание? На собеседовании думаю врятли спросят...

Comment: нет такого понятия, как `стандартный класс`

Comment: Я думаю речь идет о количестве классов в .Net Framework

Comment: B. Vandyshev, Вы правы.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Если считать стандартными классами .NET все типы (в том числе непубличные), расположенные в управляемых сборках в подкаталоге `%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\` соответствующей версии, для которых Type.IsClass возвращает true, можно посчитать их так:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static uint CountClasses(string asspath)
        {
            uint res = 0;
            Assembly ass = Assembly.LoadFile(asspath);

            foreach (var type in ass.GetTypes())
            {
                if ( type.IsClass)
                {                    
                    res++;
                }

            }

            return res;
        }

        static uint ProcessDirectory(string path)
        {
            uint res = 0;

            var files = Directory.GetFiles(path);

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                if (Path.GetExtension(file).ToUpper() == ".DLL")
                {
                    
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", file);
                    try
                    {
                        res += CountClasses(file);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);                            
                    }
                }                
            }

            var dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
            foreach (var dir in dirs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", dir);
                res += ProcessDirectory(dir);
            }
            return res;
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var count = ProcessDirectory(@"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\");
            Console.WriteLine("Classes: {0}", count);
            Console.ReadKey();            
        }
    }
}
```

Результаты:

| Версия | Классов |
| --- | --- |
| .NET 4.7.2 | 43310 |
| .NET 3.5 | 19785 (*) |

* - сумма результатов по каталогам 2.0, 3.0 и 3.5, так как это одна версия

Comment: Вот этот вариант понадёжнее будет за счёт рефлексии, чем обход офсайта. Кроме того, импонирует, что есть привязка к конкретной версии фреймворка. Так что сюда не просто апвоут, но и галка напрашивается.

Comment: @AK, а там точно ничего лишнего не будет? У меня вот этот же код другое количество возвращает (~38к для .NET 4.7.2). Хотя, вопрос, без сомнения, плох, т.к. непонятно что понимать под стандартными классами — только ли BCL? или может FCL тоже? (в любом случае надо сканировать не всю папку, а составить полный перечень необходимых сборок и сканировать только их) А вот Core сейчас вообще модульное и там сборки можно подключать выборочно только нужные, не загружая всю BCL даже вроде...

Comment: Вот, кстати, связанный вопрос и ответ к нему: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/239262/218063 ну и комментарии там есть

Comment: @АндрейNOP 38К возможно из-за того, что вы собираете 64-битное приложение. Его надо натравливать на каталог Framework64 вместо Framework, тогда число должно получиться похожим.

Comment: Неа, у меня на рабочем ПК даже ОС 32-битная :(

Answer (score 9):

Уважаемый, ну мы же с вами программисты, что мешает нам написать простейшую программу по подсчету этих классов? Благо Microsoft [выкладывает](https://referencesource.microsoft.com) исходный код в удобном формате!

Попробуем это сделать?

1. Добавляем в проект что нибудь для работы с HTML кодом, я буду использовать `HtmlAgilityPack`.
2. Заходим на нужный нам [сайт](https://referencesource.microsoft.com) и анализируем его:

   - Сбоку видим группы всяких namespace, просмотрев процесс загрузки сайта, мы увидим, что все это грузится со страницы `/results.html`.
   - Каждый namespace ведет по адресу `/#mscorlib,namespaces`. Опять смотрим как и от куда грузиться и получаем следующий адрес: `/mscorlib/namespaces.html`.
   - Теперь нужные нам классы. К сожалению Microsoft не делает пометок, что за тип такой в коде, но зато он отображает картинку типа, поигравшись с адресом изображений мы узнаем, что за классы отвечают изображения от `../content/icons/0.png` до `../content/icons/5.png`
3. Имея все эти данные - начинаем набрасывать код. Первым делом подготовим все необходимое, а точнее: вынесем адреса изображений в массив, а также сделаем базовый `Uri`:

   ```
   public static Uri BaseUri = new Uri("https://referencesource.microsoft.com/");
   public static List<string> ClassImages = new List<string>
   {
       "../content/icons/0.png",
       "../content/icons/1.png",
       "../content/icons/2.png",
       "../content/icons/3.png",
       "../content/icons/4.png",
       "../content/icons/5.png"
   };
   ```
4. Создадим простой класс, который будет отправлять запрос и отдавать нам HTML:

   ```
   public static async Task<string> Get(Uri uri)
   {
       string data;
       var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
       using (var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler { CookieContainer = cookieContainer })
       {
           using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
           {
               data = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);
           }
       }

       return HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(data);
   }
   ```
5. Создадим класс для одного Namespace. Так, как в коде Microsoft зовут это как Group - я решил не отставать от них:

   ```
   class Group
   {
       public string Namespace { get; set; }
       public string Type { get; set; }
       public Uri Uri { get; set; }
       public int Classes { get; set; }
   }
   ```
6. Теперь сделаем метод, который будет отдавать нам список всех Namespace на странице:

   ```
   public static async Task<IEnumerable<Group>> GetGroups()
   {
       List<Group> groups = new List<Group>();
       var result = await Get(new Uri(BaseUri, "results.html"));
       var html = new HtmlDocument();
       html.LoadHtml(result);

       var groupsNodes = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='resultGroup']/a");
       if (groupsNodes != null)
       {
           foreach (var group in groupsNodes)
           {
               var link = group.GetAttributeValue("href", null);
               if (link != null)
               {
                   var arr = link.Split(',');
                   var nspace = arr[0].TrimStart('/', '#');
                   var type = arr[1];

                   groups.Add(new Group
                   {
                       Namespace = nspace,
                       Type = type,
                       Uri = new Uri(BaseUri, $"{nspace}/{type}.html")
                   });

               }
           }
       }

       return groups;
   }
   ```
7. Теперь сделаем метод для подсчета изображений на странице конкретного Namespace (так, как Microsoft не очень любят частых подключений, делаем 3 попытки и увеличиваем интервал между подключениями):

   ```
   public static async Task<bool> CountClasses(Group group)
   {
       if (group == null) return false;

       try
       {
           var result = await Get(group.Uri);
           var html = new HtmlDocument();
           html.LoadHtml(result);

           var classesIcons = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img[@class='tDNI']")
               .Select(x => x.GetAttributeValue("src", null))
               .Where(x => ClassImages.Contains(x));

           group.Classes = classesIcons.Count();
           return true;
       }
       catch (Exception )
       {
           return false;
       }
   }
   ```
8. Теперь объединим все это:

   ```
   public static async Task Main(string[] args)
   {
       var groups = await GetGroups();
       var list = groups.ToList();

       int count = 1;
       foreach (var group in list)
       {
           Console.Write($"[{count}/{list.Count}] {group.Namespace}. ");

           var status = false;
           var attempt = 0;

           while (!status)
           {
               status = await CountClasses(group);
               await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
               if (attempt >= 3) break;
               if (!status) attempt++;
           }

           Console.WriteLine($"Результат: {group.Classes}");
           count++;
       }

       Console.WriteLine($"Всего: {list.Sum(x=>x.Classes)}");
       Console.ReadKey();
   }
   ```
9. Запускаем и любуемся результатом:

   ```
   [1/113] mscorlib. Результат: 1901
   [2/113] PresentationFramework. Результат: 1793
   [3/113] System.Web. Результат: 1854
   [4/113] System. Результат: 1431
   [5/113] System.Windows.Forms. Результат: 1381
   [6/113] PresentationCore. Результат: 1203
   [7/113] System.ServiceModel. Результат: 3216
   [8/113] System.Data. Результат: 675
   [9/113] System.Data.Entity. Результат: 1280
   [10/113] System.Core. Результат: 668
   [11/113] System.Xml. Результат: 702
   [12/113] System.Activities. Результат: 705
   [13/113] WindowsBase. Результат: 416
   [14/113] System.Activities.Presentation. Результат: 705
   [15/113] System.Drawing. Результат: 175
   [16/113] Microsoft.VisualBasic. Результат: 86
   [17/113] System.IdentityModel. Результат: 612
   [18/113] System.Web.Extensions. Результат: 310
   [19/113] System.Runtime.Serialization. Результат: 326
   [20/113] System.Workflow.ComponentModel. Результат: 517
   [21/113] System.Data.SqlXml. Результат: 313
   [22/113] System.Data.Linq. Результат: 377
   [23/113] UIAutomationClientsideProviders. Результат: 107
   [24/113] PresentationBuildTasks. Результат: 211
   [25/113] System.Configuration. Результат: 155
   [26/113] System.Management. Результат: 109
   [27/113] System.Data.Services. Результат: 184
   [28/113] System.IO.Compression.FileSystem. Результат: 2
   [29/113] System.IO.Log. Результат: 49
   [30/113] System.Workflow.Activities. Результат: 411
   [31/113] System.Management.Automation. Результат: 1638
   [32/113] Microsoft.CSharp. Результат: 7
   [33/113] System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap. Результат: 0
   [34/113] System.Web.Mobile. Результат: 348
   [35/113] System.Web.Services. Результат: 304
   [36/113] System.Security. Результат: 117
   [37/113] System.Data.Services.Client. Результат: 137
   [38/113] System.ServiceModel.Web. Результат: 131
   [39/113] System.ServiceModel.Activities. Результат: 274
   [40/113] System.Workflow.Runtime. Результат: 196
   [41/113] System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations. Результат: 58
   [42/113] System.Activities.Core.Presentation. Результат: 171
   [43/113] System.Design. Результат: 825
   [44/113] Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0. Результат: 283
   [45/113] UIAutomationClient. Результат: 81
   [46/113] System.Runtime.Remoting. Результат: 155
   [47/113] Microsoft.JScript. Результат: 156
   [48/113] System.Xml.Linq. Результат: 46
   [49/113] System.Net. Результат: 70
   [50/113] Microsoft.Build.Engine. Результат: 210
   [51/113] System.Transactions. Результат: 170
   [52/113] System.Messaging. Результат: 63
   [53/113] System.Data.Entity.Design. Результат: 71
   [54/113] Microsoft.Transactions.Bridge. Результат: 439
   [55/113] Accessibility. Результат: 1
   [56/113] System.ServiceModel.Internals. Результат: 129
   [57/113] System.Web.DynamicData. Результат: 82
   [58/113] System.WorkflowServices. Результат: 170
   [59/113] System.ServiceModel.Discovery. Результат: 206
   [60/113] ReachFramework. Результат: 327
   [61/113] ComSvcConfig. Результат: 31
   [62/113] System.AddIn. Результат: 61
   [63/113] System.Runtime.Caching. Результат: 39
   [64/113] System.ServiceModel.Activation. Результат: 83
   [65/113] System.Xaml. Результат: 83
   [66/113] SMSvcHost. Результат: 45
   [67/113] System.ComponentModel.Composition. Результат: 108
   [68/113] System.Deployment. Результат: 214
   [69/113] System.Printing. Результат: 124
   [70/113] System.Activities.DurableInstancing. Результат: 47
   [71/113] Microsoft.Build.Framework. Результат: 48
   [72/113] Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0. Результат: 43
   [73/113] Microsoft.Web.Administration. Результат: 73
   [74/113] System.DirectoryServices. Результат: 104
   [75/113] System.Numerics. Результат: 5
   [76/113] System.ServiceModel.Channels. Результат: 72
   [77/113] PresentationFramework.Aero. Результат: 14
   [78/113] System.Runtime.DurableInstancing. Результат: 47
   [79/113] WsatConfig. Результат: 56
   [80/113] WsatUI. Результат: 45
   [81/113] PresentationUI. Результат: 73
   [82/113] System.Web.ApplicationServices. Результат: 14
   [83/113] System.Data.Services.Design. Результат: 48
   [84/113] PresentationFramework.Luna. Результат: 9
   [85/113] System.Web.Entity. Результат: 33
   [86/113] System.EnterpriseServices. Результат: 80
   [87/113] XamlBuildTask. Результат: 32
   [88/113] System.Data.DataSetExtensions. Результат: 14
   [89/113] PresentationFramework.Royale. Результат: 9
   [90/113] SMDiagnostics. Результат: 22
   [91/113] System.Web.Extensions.Design. Результат: 89
   [92/113] System.ServiceModel.Routing. Результат: 60
   [93/113] System.IdentityModel.Selectors. Результат: 50
   [94/113] UIAutomationTypes. Результат: 37
   [95/113] System.ServiceProcess. Результат: 15
   [96/113] Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v3.5. Результат: 27
   [97/113] System.DirectoryServices.Protocols. Результат: 76
   [98/113] PresentationFramework.Classic. Результат: 10
   [99/113] System.Web.Entity.Design. Результат: 28
   [100/113] Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities.Compiler. Результат: 15
   [101/113] UIAutomationProvider. Результат: 1
   [102/113] System.ServiceModel.WasHosting. Результат: 16
   [103/113] svcutil. Результат: 4
   [104/113] System.Web.RegularExpressions. Результат: 76
   [105/113] System.AddIn.Contract. Результат: 2
   [106/113] System.Configuration.Install. Результат: 16
   [107/113] System.Web.DataVisualization. Результат: 304
   [108/113] System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization. Результат: 264
   [109/113] WindowsFormsIntegration. Результат: 8
   [110/113] System.Xaml.Hosting. Результат: 13
   [111/113] System.Drawing.Design. Результат: 15
   [112/113] System.Windows.Presentation. Результат: 2
   [113/113] System.Windows.Input.Manipulations. Результат: 13
   Всего: 31556
   ```

Получаем ответ: **~31556 класса в C#**.
P.S. Не стал расписывать как и что тут работает, а также не стал делать многопоточность и прочее (ибо программа на один запуск).

Также можно заметить, что `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap` выдал `0`, это потому что сервер меня походу заблокировал и выдает вечно `Server encountered an internal error.`. Так что в общий подсчет этот Namestace не вошел.

И также, хочу заметить, что я не уверен, что все классы здесь находятся или все грамотно отображаются в боковом меню на сайте. По этому результат приблизительный...

Comment: Благодарю за оригинальное решение!