# Как мне получить Assembly по названию проекта?

Tags: c#, рефлексия

Моя задача: вытащить из проекта все классы, имена которых содержат "API". Еще известно, что такие классы будут лежать в проектах, имена которых, содержат "Abstractions"

Я сделал следующее:

```
private List<string> GetProjectsNamesInSolution()
{
     var solutionFile = SolutionFile
          .Parse( @"..\.sln" );

     var projects = solutionFile.ProjectsInOrder
          .OrderBy( x => x.ProjectName )
          .Where( x => x.ProjectName
              .ToLowerInvariant()
              .Contains( "abstractions" ) )
          .Select( x => x.ProjectName )
          .ToList();

     return projects;
}
```

Таким образом, я получил все имена проектов. Как мне теперь взять все нужные классы из этих проектов?

я попробовал так

```
var assemblies = projectsNames
        .Select( projectName => Assembly.Load( projectName ) );
```

но, к сожалению, не все ассембли загружаются

Comment: Вы будете вместе с проектом таскать и исходный код, чтоб через него все получить?) Не кажется это странным? Обычно исходный код, это самое сокровенное проекта, его видят только единицы, если конечно это не OpenSource и то, даже там как то странно видеть загрузку `.sln` файла ради того, чтоб получить классы... Так что, я думаю вы сразу понимаете, что не в ту сторону пошли) Вам нужны такие методы как `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`, или `.GetReferencedAssemblies()`, через которые вы получите все нужные сборки, а там уже получайте классы.

Comment: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() возвращает совсем другое же. Я запускаю код в одном из проектов, находящихся в sln. То, что вы написали, вернет Assembly в которой происходит запуск кода

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под " вместе с проектом таскать и исходный код", это же не так работает

Comment: Цель этого всего в чем можете объяснить? Вот вы пишете рефлексия, то есть, вам во время выполнения процесса, надо получить из него все классы (включая подключенные библиотеки), я вот так это понимаю. Но вы тем временем, грузите `.sln` файл (исходный код проекта), считая из него данные, и работая именно с исходниками, зачем тогда вам рефлексия, если можно распарсить исходники (Roslyn например)?

Comment: Вот допустим код: `var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(... условие ...);`, я получу все подключенные библиотеки и текущую. Дальше допустим простым `var classes = assemblies.SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes().Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("Test") && x.IsClass));` я получу все классы из этих сборок, которые начинаются на `Test`, в итоге у меня в одном проекте (библиотеке) 2 класса (`Test1` и `Test2`), а в главном проекте всего один `Test3`, вот [я их и получил](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTRPC.png). Без `.sln` и прочего.

Comment: задача такая: понять сколько у нас событий в системе. События всегда хранятся в классах, которые имеют в названии "API". Ну и чтобы это все получить, я просто создал тестовое консольное приложение, которое я запущу, да получу все, что мне нужно. Это не публичное апи, а скорее тестовый research проект

Comment: ну и мне как-то не хочется все проекты с названием "abstractions" подключать

Comment: А вам и не говорят подключать, но загрузить вы их должны. Я вам лишь показал пример того, как все подключенные (и то, которые только используются, ибо если подключить и не использовать, компилятор такие ссылки убирает) `Assembly` просчитывать, а дальше уже подстраивайте под свои нужды. Вот допустим пример [подсчета кол-ва классов в .NET Framework](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/882523/220553), как видите, берется путь, в нем ищутся все `.dll`, через `Assembly.LoadFile()` грузится, ну а дальше вытягивается нужное.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо, мне помог ваш совет

Answer (score 0):

ну у меня как-то так получилось

```
public class GetClassFields
{
    private const string BasePath 
        = @"C:\Desktop\dotnet\";

    private const string NetStandardPath
        = @"\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\win-x64\";

    private const string Net6Path
        = @"\bin\Debug\net6.0\win-x64\";

    static public IEnumerable<Type> GetClasses()
        => GetAssemblies()
            .SelectMany( GetTypesWithHelpAttribute );
    
    static IEnumerable<Type> GetTypesWithHelpAttribute( Assembly assembly )
        => assembly
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(type => type
                .GetCustomAttributes( typeof(ApiEventsAttribute), true)
                .Length > 0);

    static private IEnumerable<Assembly> GetAssemblies()
    {
        var assemblies = new List<Assembly>();
        ProjectsNamesInSolution()
            .ForEach( projectName =>
            {
                var net6Path = $"{BasePath}{projectName}{Net6Path}{projectName}.dll";
                var netstandardPath = $"{BasePath}{projectName}{NetStandardPath}{projectName}.dll";

                match( LoadAssembly( netstandardPath ),
                    Succ: assembly => assemblies.Add( assembly ),
                    Fail: _ => assemblies.Add( Assembly.LoadFrom( net6Path ) ) );
            } );

        return assemblies;
    }

    static private Try<Assembly> LoadAssembly( string path )
        => () => Assembly.LoadFrom( path );

    static private List<string> ProjectsNamesInSolution()
    {
        var solutionFile = SolutionFile
            .Parse( @".sln" );
        
        var projects = solutionFile.ProjectsInOrder
            .OrderBy( x => x.ProjectName )
            .Where( x => x.ProjectType == SolutionProjectType.KnownToBeMSBuildFormat)
            .Where( x => x.ProjectName
                .ToLowerInvariant()
                .Contains( "abstractions" ) )
            .Select( x => x.ProjectName )
            .ToList();

        return projects;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).